# Filter log4j appender to only include messages from class

Tags: class, filter, log4j, appender

I am trying to create a log4j file appender that includes only messages for a specific class.  Here is an example message:

2015-08-06 16:41:43,773 [pool-3-thread-8] INFO  ACME.log- new test message

Where I want all log messages for ACME.log to go to a specific appender.  Here is code I currently have in properties file that is not working.

```
log4j.appender.myLog = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.myLog.File = /opt/netiq/idm/apps/tomcat/logs/acme.log
log4j.appender.myLog.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.myLog.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %m%n
log4j.appender.myLog.filter.filter.ID=ACME.log
log4j.appender.myLog.filter.ID.levelMin=INFO
log4j.appender.myLog.filter.ID.levelMax=ERROR
log4j.appender.myLog.filter.2 = org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using log4j 1.x, we strongly recommend that you use [**`org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender`**](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/RollingFileAppender.html) <sup>**1**</sup> instead of [`org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html) (may lose messages, [Bug 43374](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43374)).

So the configuration of you appender can be:

```
log4j.appender.myLog=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.myLog.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.myLog.rollingPolicy.fileNamePattern=/path/acme%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
log4j.appender.myLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.myLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p (%c.java:%L).%M - %m%n
log4j.appender.myLog.filter.A=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter
log4j.appender.myLog.filter.A.LevelMin=INFO    
log4j.appender.myLog.filter.A.LevelMax=ERROR
log4j.appender.myLog.filter.A.AcceptOnMatch=true
```

If you only want the log of a class (e.g. `com.company.MyClass`), you specify it as follows:

```
log4j.logger.com.company.MyClass=TRACE, myLog
```

---

*Notes*

1. In that case, you need to add the respective jar ([apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=log4j/apache-log4j-extras/1.2.17/apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar)).